# Suppose that Z has a standard normal distribution. Find the density function of $U = Z^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that Z has a standard normal distribution.
Find the density function of $U = Z^2$.

First of all, do I need to use probability function for normal distribution to find the cdf for U. If so, how can I the range of value for U. Are they just without lower and upper bound? Could someone set up or give some hints for approaching it?

Comment: Why not use the standard change of variable procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the PDF of $Z$ is $$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}, \quad -\infty < z < \infty.$$  Then the CDF of $U = Z^2$ is $$F_U(u) = \Pr[Z^2 \le u] = \Pr[-\sqrt{u} \le Z \le \sqrt{u}] = 2 \int_{z=0}^\sqrt{u} f_Z(z) \, dz.$$  Then differentiating and using the fundamental theorem of calculus,  $$f_U(u) = 2 f_Z(\sqrt{u}) \frac{d}{du}[\sqrt{u}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} f_Z(\sqrt{u}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi u}}e^{-u/2}, \quad u > 0. $$  This is a $\chi^2(1)$ density.

Comment: how can you assume that $\sigma = 1$ and $\mu = 0$?

Comment: You yourself wrote:  "Suppose that $Z$ has a **standard normal** distribution."  A standard normal distribution has mean $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 1$, by definition.